# Compactly supported cohomology of open disk plus a point

Tags: algebraic-topology, compactness, homology-cohomology, mayer-vietoris-sequence

Let $X=\{v\in\Bbb R^2:\|v\|<1\}\cup\{(-1,0)\}$, that is, the open unit disk union a point on its boundary. (Here, $(-1,0)$ refers to a point in the plane, not an interval.)

What is $H_c^•(X)$, that is, the cohomology of $X$ with compact supports?

I'm having trouble thinking about this since $X$ is not locally compact, so it's messing with my intuition. I feel like $\chi_c(X)$ should be $2$ (i.e. $\chi_c({\rm pt})+\chi_c({\rm disk})$), but I'm having trouble making that happen.

Comment: $X$ is contractible btw.

Comment: @freakish Yes, but cohomology with compact support is not a homotopy invariant. Note that $H_c^n(\Bbb R^n)=\Bbb Z$ despite $\Bbb R^n$ being contractible, for example.

Comment: Oops, you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counter-intuitively (at least to me), I think it vanishes. For each natural $n$, let $K_n$ be the union of the closed disk of radius $1-\frac{1}{n}$ about $(0,0)$ and a line connecting $(0,0)$ to $(-1,0)$. This is an increasing sequence of compact subspaces exhausting $X$, so we can compute $H_c^{\bullet}(X)=\varprojlim H^{\bullet}(X,X\setminus K_n)$, but $X$ and $X\setminus K_n$ are contractible spaces (the latter are all homeomorphic to open squares), so $(X,X\setminus K_n)$ are acyclic pairs by their LES (and $H^0$ vanishes as well), whence $H_c^{\bullet}(X)=0$.

Comment: Weird. I had been led to believe that $\chi_c$ equaled the geometric Euler characteristic. (If $X=\coprod_\alpha\sigma_\alpha$ is partitioned into finitely many disjoint open cells, the geometric (or combinatorial) Euler characteristic is defined to be $\sum_\alpha(-1)^{\dim\sigma_\alpha}$. In this case it's $(-1)^0+(-1)^2=2$.) I suppose I was wrong there then. (Perhaps they agree for locally compact spaces? For compact spaces they both are the plain vanilla Euler characteristic.)

Comment: My confusion has been cleared up by this: https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/journals/items/hha/content/vols/0013/0002/a011/ Essentially, the combinatorial (aka geometric) Euler characteristic, which is denoted there by ${\rm eu}(X)$, is only guaranteed to equal the Euler char. of the comp. supp. cohom. (denoted by $\chi_c(X)$) when $X$ is locally compact, as I said. To define ${\rm eu}(X)$ topologically for other spaces, first define$$z(X)=\{x\in X\mid\text{$x$ has a compact neighborhood in $X$}\}$$and then let ${\rm eu}(X)$ be $\chi_c(z(X))+\chi_c(z(X-z(X)))+\dotsb$. (Cont'd)

Comment: In our example, the other terms (continuing with $\chi_c(z(X-\text{the previous terms})$ etc) all vanish, and we're left with ${\rm eu}(X)=\chi_c({\rm disk})+\chi_c({\rm pt})=2$, as expected. \\

Sidenote: at the end of that paper, the author notes that "I do not know of a counterexample to ${\rm eu}(X) = \chi_c(X)$". Well, I believe we have now found one.